# Копировать работающий Docker container со всеми процессами

Tags: docker

У меня есть Docker container с работающими процессами. Есть ли способ скопировать его в новый образ и начать использовать новый образ?

Comment: В образе нету процессов

Comment: Если вы ведете речь про то, что в контейнере сделали изменение и хотите их сохранить, то воспользуйтесь commit - вот тут как это сделать https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Но очевидно что "скопировать работающие процессы" звучит довольно странно. Процессы так или иначе вы запускаете в итоге сами стартуя контейнер, явно или не явно указывая собственно сам процеес.